# How to overcome CATIA.FileSelectionBox() error without setting "regserver option" as administrator?

Tags: vba, dialog, catia

The following code runs well if I have administrator permissions. But it doesn't work at all for a user.

```
Sub CATMain()
On Error Resume Next
Dim strpath As String

strpath = CATIA.FileSelectionBox("Select file", "*.xlsx", 
CatFileSelectionModeOpen)

End Sub
```

I think CATIA.FileSelectionBox() works fine in CATScript so I was thinking in run a CATScript with Application.ExecuteScript(). When I try to do it another error pops up "Function or interface marked as restricted...". Can anyone give me an alternative method? Would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this all the code you are executing? This kind of problem generally happens when invoking a method from a typed variable. Simple by declaring it as a variant instead of it real type corrects the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I know that "Function or interface marked as restricted..." error could be solved as you say, but It did not work. Thank you again! I've already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my answer. Thanks for letting me post my question in here. Next, I post a code that works just fine. The only thing that remains incomplete is that I can not add filters for types of files like *.CATParts or *.CATProducts in this code. But it works for me already.

```
Function SelectFile( )
' File Browser via HTA
' Author:   Rudi Degrande, modifications by Denis St-Pierre and Rob van der 
Woude
' Features: Works in Windows Vista and up (Should also work in XP).
'           Fairly fast.
'           All native code/controls (No 3rd party DLL/ XP DLL).
' Caveats:  Cannot define default starting folder.
'           Uses last folder used with MSHTA.EXE stored in Binary in 
[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32].
'           Dialog title says "Choose file to upload".
' Source:   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-
US/a3b358e8-15ae-4ba3-bca5-ec349df65ef6/windows7-vbscript-open-file-dialog-
box-fakepath?forum=ITCG

Dim objExec, strMSHTA, wshShell

SelectFile = ""

' For use in HTAs as well as "plain" VBScript:
strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:" & "<" & "input type=file id=FILE>" _
         & "<" & "script>FILE.click();new 
ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" _
         & 
".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);" & "<" & 
"/script>"""
' For use in "plain" VBScript only:
' strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE>" _
'          & "<script>FILE.click();new 
ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" _
'          & 
".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);
</script>"""

Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set objExec = wshShell.Exec( strMSHTA )

SelectFile = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine( )

Set objExec = Nothing
Set wshShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Kind regards